# Gradle Install Issue with id 'org.grails.grails-plugin'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gradle

I am trying to run `gradle install` for setup on my mac. I have the following build.gradle file and I am getting an error like this:

the error I am getting:

```
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'owf-auditing'.
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'org.grails.grails-plugin']
   > Could not get unknown property 'classesDir' for main classes of type org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultSourceSetOutput.
```

Here is the gradle.build file that i have.

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        grailsVersion = '3.3.2'
        gormVersion = '6.1.8.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
        maven { url 'https://repo.grails.org/grails/core' }
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath group: 'io.spring.gradle', name: 'dependency-management-plugin', version: '1.0.4.RELEASE'

        classpath group: 'org.grails', name: 'grails-gradle-plugin', version: grailsVersion
    }
}


group 'org.ozoneplatform'
version '1.3.2-0'


apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'java'

apply plugin: 'org.grails.grails-plugin'
apply plugin: 'org.grails.grails-plugin-publish'


repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://repo.grails.org/grails/core' }
    maven { url 'http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release' }
    maven { url 'http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external' }
    maven { url 'https://packages.atlassian.com/3rdparty/' }
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom 'org.grails:grails-bom:' + grailsVersion
        mavenBom 'org.ozoneplatform:ozone-classic-bom:7.17.2-0'
    }

    applyMavenExclusions false
}

dependencies {
    // Spring Boot
    provided group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-autoconfigure'
    provided group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-logging'

    // Grails
    compile group: 'org.grails', name: 'grails-core'

    compile group: 'org.grails.plugins', name: 'hibernate5'
    compile group: 'org.grails.plugins', name: 'quartz'

    console group: 'org.grails', name: 'grails-console'

    profile group: 'org.grails.profiles', name: 'plugin'

    provided group: 'org.grails', name: 'grails-web-boot'
    provided group: 'org.grails', name: 'grails-plugin-services'
    provided group: 'org.grails', name: 'grails-plugin-domain-class'

    testCompile group: 'org.grails', name: 'grails-plugin-testing'
    testCompile group: 'org.grails', name: 'grails-gorm-testing-support'

    // Other
    compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-core'

    compile group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'javax.servlet-api'
}


bootRun {
    jvmArgs('-Dspring.output.ansi.enabled=always')
    addResources = true
}


task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '4.2.1'
}
```

I am not sure why I am getting this error. I have the latest version of gradle. I installed it from their website and i also tried `brew install gradle`. Can anyone help me with this.

it said the error is coming from the following line:

`org.grails.grails-plugin-publish`

Comment: are you running gradle install or do you mean to run gralde install?

Comment: I want to run `gradle install` within the directory

Comment: my machine has gradle 5.4 installed through bew install gradle @richardwhitney

Comment: ok you had a typo in your title and in your request it read Gralde

Answer (score 0):

Check the version of Gradle you are running with `gradle install`. It seems, it's not a 4.2.1 as it use to be, according to your `build.gradle` script. Look at this:

```
task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '4.2.1'
}
```

This is a configuration part for calling a [Gradle Wrapper](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html) and usually tah means, that this script is adopted to run under exactly this version of Gradle.

And the exception you've got, could mean, that you are running a newer version of Gradle, because even for 4.2.1 version of Gradle, property `classesDir` was deprecated, as it's said [here](https://docs.gradle.org/4.2.1/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.SourceSetOutput.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.SourceSetOutput:classesDir).

So you just need to run it withe Gradle version 4.2.1 or try to use a wrapper for that.